# How do I put custom wallpapers on Android market place?

Tags: android, google-play, wallpaper

I am an automotive photographer and would like to turn some of my pics into wallpaper packages to put on the Android market place.  I couldn't find anything on Google that explains how to go about this...I know someone on here knows though!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There use to be an Android example to setup making a wallpaper app.  Not sure if it is still on the developer network or not?

Android Developers resource sample

Update July 8th 2014 (I have removed plugins and with this removed all additional information as it was no longer relevant)

Comment: Cool, thanks.  So it sounds like you can't just upload a zip file to the market full of wallpapers for people to download..you have to actually create an app that includes all of the images and a UI to change the phone's wallpaper?

Comment: Hey alexD, No you cannot just load a zip file to the market.  The market is used for applications that have been developed for the Android platform.  You could always resize your images to fit for each of the display types, and then provide the images from a website for people to download.  There are many wallpaper sites, but again they provide an exact size for each device that has a different display size.  Or you could go with the Wallpaper Wizardrii option.  It provides the UI and everything else to set wallpaper, but you have to build the plugin.